# Cannot switch to jenkins user on aws ec2 linux?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

When I ssh into an aws ec2 Linux instance, I am `ec2-user`. The instance is a Jenkins master. When I try `su - jenkins` and entered the correct password, the system says `Last login: ....` which looks like the switching succeeded. But `whoami` says I'm still `ec2-user`.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jenkins is a service account, it doesn't have a shell by design. It is generally accepted that service accounts shouldn't be able to log in interactively.

if you really want to login as Jenkins, you can do so with: `sudo su -s /bin/bash jenkins`

Comment: Thanks for this. When I do login this way, I have not even permissions to run `ls`, however. I was previously able to login as jenkins user on a previous ec2 with Jenkins, but for some reason I have spun up another one and not able to login with `sudo su - jenkins`